# Turn a list of javascript variables into object key/value pairs

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I need help making a function that turns this list of variables:

```
var a = {bacon: 12, chicken: 2};
var b = {bacon: 10, chicken: 5};
```

into this object:

```
var obj = {
    a: {bacon: 12, chicken: 2},
    b: {bacon: 10, chicken: 5}
};
```

Comment: Nice to know, then what is your question? What went wrong when you tried?

Comment: Sorry, clarified my question

Comment: Do you know the list of variables ahead of time? Are they fields on an object, global variables, or just locals?

Comment: You don't seem to have a list of variables.  You seem to have some individual variables and an object.

Comment: The correct answer is below. Your best bet is to create and use an object instead of variables from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because the variable names are not accessible via the code.  There is no function to come to know the name of a variable associated with a value, e.g. going from {bacon: 12, chicken: 2} to "a".

Answer (score -1):

u could use an array instead:

```
var obj = [a,b]

obj[0].bacon //returns 12
```

Edited: use this instead

```
JSON.parse('{"a":"+JSON.stringify(a)+","b":"+JSON.stringify(b)+"}')
```

Comment: This doesn't do what they want at all.